# Set proxy settings for network only

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, internet, proxy

I'm on Xubuntu 18.04. I'm trying use proxy but u only want it for a single network. Is there a way to do that? I would use commands but they're too hard to change back

Comment: the pac script was made for it : conditional use of some proxy. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config

Comment: I try to use it but the only methods options are none and automatic

Comment: we can help but more information is required: from where to use a proxy? - Browser (which one), Terminal, Whole system ?

Comment: I'm trying to use it on a single network for a torrent so I guess whole system with a PAC file.